# SQL join 4 table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
1) user-  id | nickname 
           5    hello
           6    ouuu
           7    youyou

2) team_leader-  id | user_id | team_name | game |position
                  2      5        haha      M.A     Leader
                  3      7        nono      M.A     Leader

3) team_member-  id | user_id | team_leader_id| game |position
                  1      6         2            M.A    Member


4) user_game-    id | user_id | game | character_game
                  1      5      M.A     wahaha
                  2      6      M.A     kiki
                  3      7      M.A     popo
```

i want to display the team_leader's id where id=2
so the output should be display:
Nickname   Character name    Position
hello                wahaha              Leader
ouuu                  kiki                   Member

Comment: and what do you mean by fail?

Comment: mean the result wrong

Comment: `select *` not `select*`

Comment: check your table data ...

Comment: What database? Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should **never use the `*` in queries**, as long as they aren't only for temporary testing purposes. Even if everything works as expected it can lead to unexpected errors later, e.g. when table schemata are changed. Always explicitly list the fields you wish to include in your query.

The problem with your query is that you got **name clashes** in the joined tables. Every table has an `id` field, so you have to **use alias names** and address them via qualified names to be able to clearly distinguish them.

```
SELECT u.id, u.nickname, t.id, t.user_id, t.team_name, t.game,
    tm.id, tm.user_id, tm.team_id, ug.id, ug.user_id, ug.game, ug.character_game
    FROM user AS u
    JOIN user_game AS ug
    ON ug.user_id = u.id 
    JOIN team AS t
    ON t.user_id = u.id
    JOIN team_member AS tm
    ON t.id = tm.team_id
    WHERE t.id = 2 AND ug.game = t.game
    AND tm.team_id = 2;
```

**BTW:** If your application design allows that a user can have only a part of the "subtables" referencing user_id or even none of them, you should think of using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. That would ensure that every user will have a row in the result, even those who aren't a team member, e.g.

```
SELECT u.id, u.nickname, t.id, t.user_id, t.team_name, t.game,
    tm.id, tm.user_id, tm.team_id, ug.id, ug.user_id, ug.game, ug.character_game
    FROM user AS u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_game AS ug
    ON ug.user_id = u.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN team AS t
    ON t.user_id = u.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN team_member AS tm
    ON t.id = tm.team_id
    WHERE t.id = 2 AND ug.game = t.game
    AND tm.team_id = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select * from user u
inner join team t on u.id = t.user_id
inner join team_member tm on t.user_id = tm.user_id
inner join user_game ug on t.user_id = ug.user_id and t.game = ug.game where tm.team_id = 2
```

Pay your attention to lean SQL
 joins

Answer (score 0):

***try this one:***

```
SELECT 
a.nickname,
b.position,
c.character_game
FROM user a
INNER JOIN team_leader b ON b.user_id=b.id
INNER JOIN user_game c ON c.id=c.user_id
WHERE a.id=5 OR a.id=6
```